# about Extjs afterLayout

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout

I added a listener in the code like:

```
listen: {
    afterLayout: function(){
        doSomething...
    }
}
```

the function is to render the html tags. But it does not work when the page loaded. I need to force rendering the page like change the size of browser will it work.  I wanna know why.  "afterLayout" should work automatically after the page loaded right? Or do I miss something?

Comment: @Mr.George 4.1.x  I forget the exact version cause the code is in firm.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong config. Instead of `listen: {` use `listeners: {`

Here is an example for you: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16gu

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'afterRender Test',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                afterRender: function() {
                    this.update('<div style="width:300px; background-color:red; padding:10px;">Added via afterRender listener</div>');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your remind. Actually it is listeners in my code . Here I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think the event your searching is afterrender.
Afterlayout only fires when the window size change and not on the load.
afterrender event match after the layout of the interested component is loaded.
so you should try with this:

```
listen: {
    afterrender: function(){
        doSomething...
    }
}
```

If you must call the same function in all the cases call it on afterrender and on afterlayout

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to use afterrender like you said but it did not work. I don not know why so I tried afterLayout. Is there any preconditions to make it work?. Thanks again.

Comment: try to reproduce your problem on a sencha fiddle, so i can try to directly solve the problem

Comment: afterrender is called before the rendering of subcomponents takes place! Maybe you are searching for `boxready` event, which is called once all subcomponents have been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can solve [viewport](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport).
wrap your application in this component. viewport will listen to window size change and automatically re size it's child elements (your application)